# Как удалить не одну запись, а каждую запись с search_id 1 в БД

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Как сделать метод, чтобы удалить не одну, а каждую запись со значением 1 в search_id

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это Класс HibernateUril и метод delete удаляет один запис

```
 public static void delete(String HQL){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery(HQL);
        DataEntity platform = (DataEntity) q.list().get(0);
        session.delete(platform);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Main

```
        HibernateUtil.delete("from TenderEntity where search_id = " + searchEntity.getId());
```

Comment: @Дмитрий, не всех удалить, а запись со значением 1 в search_id, я запустил метод теряют только один запис со значением 1, я отмечал зелёный квадрат хотел удалить, search_id со значением 2 остаются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставаясь в рамках этого кода:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(HQL);
for(Object entity : q.list()) {
    DataEntity platform = (DataEntity) entity;
    session.delete(platform);
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Если не используются interceptor-ы, которые должны вызываться для сущности на разных этапах ее жизненного цикла (в данном случае перед удалением), то можно сделать это одним запросом в БД без запроса на получение:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery(HQL);
query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Только клиенту этого метода, нужно будет передавать измененный запрос:

```
HibernateUtil.delete("delete TenderEntity where search_id = " + searchEntity.getId());
```